# Gstreamer Pipeline Jackaudiosrc output input

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline

I have the following problem, `jackaudiosrc` connects automatically to the first jack ports, with my capture_1 and capture_2.

I set the option `connect=O`, but this is not that what i think I want. What I want is that when I start script `jackaudiosrc` automaticly connect to another port, original script here:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! queue ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! tee name=tscreen ! queue ! autovideosink tscreen. ! queue ! theoraenc quality=16 ! queue ! oggmux name=mux jackaudiosrc connect=0 ! audio/x-raw-float,channels=2 ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc quality=0.2 ! queue ! mux. mux. ! queue ! shout2send ip=xxx port=xxx mount=test.ogg password=xxxxx name= description= genre= url=
```

I have a program `aj-snapshot`, that makes an xml file, in this file is the connect I use, here is:

```
jack
client name=idjc_default 
port name=str_out_l

connection port=idjc_default:output_in_l 

connection port=camstream1.py:in_jackaudiosrc0_1

port

port name=str_out_r

connection port=idjc_default:output_in_r

connection port=camstream1.py:in_jackaudiosrc0_2

port

client

jack
```

My Question is, how can I add connect to this ports in cmd gst-launch jackaudiosrc to automaticly connect to this ports when i start my script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this from gst-launch. You could write a small application that use gst_parse_launch and talks to jack to setup the connections.

Comment: thx for answer, i have no idee how can use it :( the orginal script is a python sript here http://pastebin.com/GffpQrdz jackaudiosrc is in. can you give me an example? gst_parse_launch in this script? thanx

Comment: your app already uses gst.parse_launch, I have no idea if there is a python api to jack (I would believe there is).